# Use-case diagram for payment scenario

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I want to clarify one scenario in use-case diagram which involve in payment. There are 2 way of doing a payment.

1. Using card
2. Using mobile number

Here want to clarify about the second one. To do a mobile base payment first user need to add the mobile number when user try to do a payment in payment page. I put that as a *extend* relationship. Please tell me is this correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, this is not correct.  Use-cases could be associated with actors but not with other use-cases: the relationship between two use-cases may be  `«extend»`, or `«include»` or specialization.  In consequence, `Add mobile number` and `mobile` can't be associated the ay you have diagrammed it.

Depending on what you mean, you may correct your diagram:

- by showing that `mobile` includes `Add mobile number` (dashed line with arrow), if you mean that **every time** `mobile` is executed,  `add mobile number` would also be executed.
- by showing that  `Add mobile number` extends `mobile` (dashed line with arrow), if you mean that **in some cases** where `mobile` is executed,  `add mobile number` could need to be executed as well.

Other notation improvement coulb be to get rid of the arrows for associations wetween actors and use-cases.  This is an obsolete notation.

Beyond these purely formal remarks,  it's important to realize that use-cases should represent goals of value for users.  While we would certainly agree that `payment` is a goal for the user, and we could certainly understand your desire to add extensions for different payment means, we would certainly not agree on the fact that `Add mobile number` is a goal for the user.  It's either functional decomposition or user-interface details, both aspects that should in principle not be documented in a UC diagram.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Actually add mobile number executes only once(first time) or whenever actor tried to add a new number. I simply remove that. It is not essentials  for the use-case.